# How to retrieve data using an Ember Local Storage Adapter?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, local-storage, ember-cli

I'm trying to understand how the [Ember Local Storage](https://github.com/funkensturm/ember-local-storage) addon works. It looks like when you use the local storage adapter, there is no way to make a request to the server anymore (tell me if I'm wrong).

So I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve my models from the server, and keep them saved in the local storage?

What is the best practise to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an adapter type for each model or for the entire application.  It seems based on your question you set the application adapter to be local storage.  What you seem to want is one model to be local and another model to be a restAdapter.

Use one model type to retrieve the data from the server then, in the serializer you can create a model which relies on the Local Storage adapter to save it locally.

Comment: Isn't any way to use the exact same model and save either on the server or on the local storage ? Maybe changing the adapter... I don't want to have duplicated models for my entire application.

Comment: I havent seen a way thats possible but from what I understand 1model=1adapter=1serializer.  What you might want to do is have a model thats using a local adapter... and just make a pure jquery call to load the data then save it into your local model.  Then you wont need 2 models.